# PHP - Convert unicode symbols

Tags: php, json, character-encoding

I have a json like this:

```
{
  "name": "TEXT \xabTEXT\xbb"
}
```

I know it isn't valid and I can't use `json_decode()`, because of `\xab` and `\xbb` which should be `«` and `»`

How could I convert them to symbols?
And handle all possible symbols like these.

Answer (score 0):

You can do somthing like this:

```
<?php
$str = "TEXT \u{ab}TEXT\u{bb}";
echo $str;
?>
```

Which outputs:
TEXT «TEXT»